# What is the correct method for conditional printing of variables?

Tags: conditionals

I hope I've used the right terms for my question.

I'm working on a template and it has variables which need to be setup by the user. Not all users have the same amount of variables. Users are students. Example: Some students may not have a co-supervisor. My template will check if that variable was defined or not and then print what is required.

I have an MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\def\mySupervisor{John Smith\xspace}
\newcommand{\theSupervisor}{Jackie Chan\xspace}

\begin{document}

\ifdefined\mySupervisor
\noindent\rule{5cm}{1pt}\\
The Supervisor\\
\mySupervisor
\else
SELF Supervision.
\fi
\end{document}
```

My questions:

1. Is this the right way to do this sort of thing?
2. Are there any quirks to the method I've used?
3. Is there a better way?
4. I'm under the impression that `\newcommand{}` is not good here?

Comment: Do not mix `\def` and `\newcommand` this way. Use the latter. Is the user really supposed to define the command him/herself?

Comment: I've put the variable definition but they should change the name or comment it out if it doesn't apply to them.

Comment: I would suggest a key-value interface rather here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a property list from `expl3` and optionally using a `key-value` interface, meaning that some keys can be set with something like `\SetupData{supervisor={foo},name={foobar}}`, however this means a lot of predefinition. This way, no separate macros for each of the keys have to be defined.

The `\SetupData` macro uses any possible key name, e.g. `birth date`, and stores the data to the property list. The `\IfStudentDataGivenTF` etc. macros check whether the key is given and branch accordingly.

The `\SetStudentData` macro behaves similar to the key - value interface, but sets all keys without defining them before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_khalid_student_prop 

\keys_define:nn {STUDENTDATA} {
  supervisor .code:n={\prop_gput:Nnn  \g_khalid_student_prop  {supervisor} {#1}},
  name .code:n={\prop_gput:Nnn  \g_khalid_student_prop  {name} {#1}}
      }


\NewDocumentCommand{\setupdata}{+m}{%
  \keys_set:nn { STUDENTDATA } {#1}
}

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \khalid_if_studentdatagiven:n { T,F, TF } {
  \prop_if_in:NnTF {\g_khalid_student_prop } {#1} { 
    \prg_return_true:
  }
  {
    \prg_return_false:
  }
}

\cs_new:Npn \retrievestudentdata#1{%
  \prop_item:Nn \g_khalid_student_prop {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\IfStudentDataGivenTF}{m+m+m}{%
  \khalid_if_studentdatagiven:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3}
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\IfStudentDataGivenT}{m+m}{%
  \khalid_if_studentdatagiven:nT {#1} {#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\IfStudentDataGivenF}{m+m}{%
  \khalid_if_studentdatagiven:nF {#1} {#2}
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\ClearStudentData}{}{%
  \prop_gclear:N \g_khalid_student_prop
}


\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn {Nox,Nxx}
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetStudentData}{+m}{
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1} 
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq {=} {##1}
    \prop_gput:Nxx \g_khalid_student_prop {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1} } {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {2} }
  }
}



\ExplSyntaxOff  

\begin{document}

\setupdata{supervisor={Jackie Chan\xspace}, name={Gandalf the Grey}}



\IfStudentDataGivenTF{supervisor}{%
\noindent\rule{5cm}{1pt}

The Supervisor

\retrievestudentdata{supervisor}

}{%
SELF Supervision
}

\IfStudentDataGivenT{name}{%

Name: 
\retrievestudentdata{name}

}

\ClearStudentData

\SetStudentData{date of birth=2018/02/30, place of birth={Middle Earth}}

\IfStudentDataGivenT{date of birth}{%
  \colorbox{yellow}{Date of birth: \retrievestudentdata{date of birth}}

  \colorbox{green}{Place of birth: \retrievestudentdata{place of birth}}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What are the benefits of such a method over creating a file of all the variables and then using `\input` in any file where you need them?

Comment: @KhalidHussain: You can incorporate this code in a package of your own and use the package in any of your template files, in addition, you can create the keys on the fly, when you need them