# Environment with key-value options using expl3

Tags: expl3, xparse

I am new to `expl3` and would like to create an environment with various key-value arguments.
At the moment I am struggling to detect weather a key was set or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% keys
\keys_define:nn { mybodule/bfigure }
{
    caption .tl_set:N = \l_mybodule_caption,
    shift .dim_set:N  = \l_mybodule_shift  ,
    shift .default:n  = 0em
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{bfigure}{O{}}{
    \keys_set:nn { mybodule/bfigure } { #1 }  
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_mybodule_caption {true} {false}
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{bfigure}[caption=mycaption]
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \end{bfigure}
\end{document}
```

What it the correct way to implement the `if caption set then ... else ...` part?
Am I even using the `\keys_define` and `\keys_set:nn` correctly?

Comment: Off topic: I'm wondering if you want `shift .default:n  = 0em` or `shift .initial:n  = 0em`. The `.default` value is used when you give the key without value (`[shift]`), the `.initial` value is the pre-set value that is used if the key is not used.

Comment: Your `\tl_if_empty:NTF` appears to work. Since a newly define `tl` variable is always empty your code should also be safe. But you should probably wait for a real `expl3` expert for confirmation. If you want to be on the safe side you can add `caption .initial:n = {},`, but if I'm right this is not needed as long as you keep your `\keys_set:nn { mybodule/bfigure } { #1 }` calls local and don't re-use `\l_mybodule_caption` anywhere.

Comment: FWIW the answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417064/35864 uses several `.tl_set:N`s and checks for their presence with `\tl_if_empty:NTF`/`\tl_if_empty:NF`. Look for `\l_guide_number_tl` and `\l_guide_keywords_tl`.

Comment: `\l_mybodule_caption` should probably be called `\l_mybodule_caption_tl` and `\l_mybodule_shift` would be `\l_mybodule_shift_dim` if you want to follow `expl3` naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the keys inside an environment, you need not worry about their initial values in a different environment, because the assigned values will be forgotten as soon as the environment ends.

For instance

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% keys
\keys_define:nn { mybodule/bfigure }
{
    caption .tl_set:N = \l_mybodule_caption_tl,
    shift .dim_set:N  = \l_mybodule_shift_dim,
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{bfigure}{O{}}
{
    \keys_set:nn { mybodule/bfigure } { #1 }  
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_mybodule_caption_tl {true} {false}
}
{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{bfigure}
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
\end{bfigure}

\begin{bfigure}[caption=mycaption]
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
\end{bfigure}

\begin{bfigure}
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
\end{bfigure}

\end{document}
```

will produce

[image]

Please, use the proper naming conventions, ending each variable's name with the variable type.

Note that `.default` is *not* the initial value given to the key, but the value assigned if no `=` symbol follows the key. If you want to assign an initial value to a key, to be used when the key is not supplied, use

```
shift .initial = 12pt,
```

or whatever value. Stating `0pt` as initial value is not necessary, because `dim` variables are initialized to be zero, just like `tl` variables are initialized to empty.

If you want to print the caption if the key has been set, do

```
\tl_if_empty:NF \l_mybodule_caption_tl
 {
  \caption{\l_mybodule_caption_tl}
 }
```

at the appropriate spot.